# Android OpenGL ES 2.0: How to convert bitmap to mp4 video?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have one photo and want add animation to it, such as rotate 360 degree and duration is 5 seconds, I use GLSurfaceView to play it on screen, now I need export it as mp4, how to do it?

os:Android and OpenGL ES 2.0

Comment: the incompetence of the moderators is amazing, if they think the question is wrong, they put a minus. But the question is very interesting and correct.

Answer (score 0):

Each frame you need to render to a texture, and then get a Bitmap and add to the video.